# If $P(x)>Q(x)^2+Q(x)+x^2-6$ $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$, show that there exists two roots which satisfy $| \alpha - \beta | <1$

Tags: polynomials

[image]

Someone suggested me that it's just factorisation followed by Pigeonhole Principle. I don't find any way to continue from there. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_6$ be the roots of $P(x)$.

Suppose that 
$$a_{i+1}-a_i\ge 1\qquad \text{for}\quad i=1,2,\cdots, 5$$
from which we have
$$a_6-a_1\ge 5\tag1$$

Now, we have
$$(P(a_i)=)\ \ 0\gt Q(a_i)^2+Q(a_i)+a_i^2-6$$
Considering the discriminant of the RHS, we have to have
$$1^2-4\cdot 1\cdot (a_i^2-6)\gt 0,$$
i.e.
$$-2.5\lt a_i\lt 2.5$$

It follows that $$a_6-a_1\lt 5$$
which contradicts $(1)$.

Comment: I see where we could've used PHP. From $-2.5 < a_i < 2.5$, PHP would've as well yielded us $| \alpha - \beta | < 1$. Thank you!

Comment: @Mathejunior: I've taken $Q(a_i)^2+Q(a_i)+a_i^2-6\lt 0$ as a quadratic inequality on $Q(a_i)$. If $D\le 0$, then there are no $Q(a_i)$ satisfying the inequality. So, we have to have $D\gt 0$.

Comment: right after posting, I understood that and deleted the comment. But anyway, thank you once again!

Comment: @Mathejunior: Ah, yes. You are welcome.